# Sanitizing strings with several types of quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping, puppeteer, etl

Working on a side-project which aggregates data from various websites, sanitizes the input data, then stores it in postgres.

Currently, I have to implement my own solutions for sanitizing dirty/ugly data, which hasn't been too bad but I've run into an issue with height measurements where there's a mixed bag of quote types, e.g. `5’4″`, `5′ 9″`

I'd like to sanitize the strings as follows:

- `’`,`′` and similar characters are replaced with single quotes for **feet**.
- `″` and similar characters are replaced with double quotes for **inches**.

Is there a library which solves this problem?
If not, is there a concise regex that provides the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex replacement with lookup approach here:

```js
var map = {};
map["’"] = "'";
map["′"] = "'";
map["″"] = "\"";

var input = "5’4″ and 5′ 9″";
var output = input.replace(/[’′″]/g, (x) => map[x]);
console.log(input + " => " + output);
```

Comment: I've been using `String.prototype.replace` for years and never knew the second argument could be a function. Thanks!